# Android MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT ignored

Tags: android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm using htc desire-HD.
When I use the camera to capture video with

```
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
```

I give it a duration limit with

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,MAX_DURATION).
```

The camera seems to ignore the duration limit.
On a Nexus-s, Motorola RAZR, Galaxy SII it does work.
Is there a different way to limit the capture video duration on htc devices?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I'd be interested if yes!

Comment: I'm also having this problem a year later. HTC and Samsung camera apps both do the same thing

Comment: Check the android version of the phone; android.intent.extra.durationLimit was introduced in API Level 8, so it should be available only from Android 2.2 (although the HTC desire HD should have version 2.3... ) (docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT )

Comment: see my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914027/mediastore-extra-duration-limit-not-working-nexus-devices/45215231#45215231"