# MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT Not working Nexus Devices?

Tags: android, video, camera

Hi All one of the Application implemented duration of video capturing, i set duration is 10 sec.

But it's not working in Nexus Devices, Except Nexus it's working fine for All Devices Can any one knows what is the issue.

Here is the Code.

```
 final int durationLimit = 10;
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, durationLimit);
 startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CODE);
```

Comment: There is no requirement for any camera app to honor `EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT`. This is a request, not a command.

Comment: @CommonsWare Any other way to limit the length of video.

Comment: Not when you delegate the work to a third-party app. You are welcome to use the camera APIs and record the video directly yourself. Or, if your concern is not with the video on the device but some subset that you need to upload, look into how you can chop off the first 10 seconds of the video, and upload that piece.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this issue, i also have this issue.

Comment: I have also this issue

Comment: see my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914027/mediastore-extra-duration-limit-not-working-nexus-devices/45215231#45215231"

Answer (score 3):

I also verified this issue exists only for Google Camera App whose Version is greater than "2.5.052(2005148-30)".

Currently, on Play store, Google Camera App version is "3.2.045(2821762-30)" by using this version you can easily reproduce this issue. Previously Google Camera EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT was working on the V2.5.052.